# pytest: Custom logger output not shown, even though log_cli is set

Tags: python, logging, pytest, python-logging

In my project, I use different loggers with different settings. I define my settings on a root logger, and each subsequent logger inherits their settings from this root logger:

```
def get_logger(name):
    root_logger = logging.getLogger(ROOT_LOGGER)
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    root_logger.propagate = False

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - [%(name)s] - %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    root_logger.addHandler(handler)

    logger = logging.getLogger(ROOT_LOGGER + "." + name)

    return logger
```

I have configured my `pytest.ini` as follows, in order to show live log outputs during the tests:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_level = INFO
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s - [%(name)s] - %(levelname)s: %(message)s
```

Now, when I run tests using my `get_logger()` function, no log is shown during execution of the tests. Take the following test for example:

```
def test_logger():
    logger = get_logger("root." + __name__) # My logger function
    logger.info("Test")
    time.sleep(2)
```

No log is shown during the test (during the 2 seconds of sleeping), only after it concludes. Furthermore, this is the test output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_misc.py::test_logger PASSED                                         [100%]2022-04-24 18:51:56,566 - [root.test_misc] - INFO: Test


============================== 1 passed in 2.03s ==============================
```

If I use `getLogger("root." + __name__)` instead of my own wrapper, where no values are set, the following output is generated:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_misc.py::test_logger 
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
18:54:03 - [root.test_misc] - INFO: Test
PASSED                                                                   [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 2.01s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, the live log call works as expected. How can I get my custom logger to work with the pytest live log call?

Comment: When I look at your `get_logger` function, you never use `root_logger`,`handler`,`formatter` because they are local to the function and go out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `logging` framework uses a singleton pattern for the loggers, each child of the root logger will obtain a reference to the `root_logger` I created and modified.

Comment: What is the value of the ROOT_LOGGER variable?

Comment: Just a string, in my case the name of the program, think "programname".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `logger.propagate = True`.  That should allow your custom logger to appear when `cli_log = 1`